# Default method cannot be static in java interface?

Tags: java, interface, static, default

Why can't we create an interface with default static method?

```
public interface StaticTest {    
  default static void display() {    
     System.out.println("Display here");  
  }  
}
```

Comment: why would you want to create a default static method?

Comment: I want to add a feature in interface which can be directly access by classes that implement it without affecting the past implementations.

Comment: then you want either a default method or a static method

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Static methods cannot be overridden or inherited in any meaningful sense, and `default` methods are there to be overridden or inherited.  Just like other non-static interface methods, but `default` specifically implies that inheritance is meaningful to this method, which is incompatible with `static`.